# Can commercial applications use Gsettings?

Tags: application-development, gsettings

According to [specified technical requirements](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/my-apps-packages/), a commercial application must be self‑contained in a single directory (which I agree is a good requirement), and use `~/.config/<app-name>` for its configuration data (good requirement too). However, Gsettings requires to have a schema file installed inside of some subdirectory of `$XDG_DATA_DIRS`. Do I have to understand commercial applications can't make use of GSettings?

## Update

I've found [another page](http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/02/how-to-prepare-a-compiled-application-for-ubuntu-software-center/), which seems to suggest requirements are not exactly that restrictive. The latter mention installation of an icon file in `/usr/share/icons/` and a desktop file in `/usr/share/applications/`. If that's OK, may be that's OK too, to install a GSettings schema in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`? That would still be better to have confirmation. I feel the first mentioned link, lacks precisions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to install schema files into `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`, they can be installed into any `${XDG_DATA_DIRS}/glib-2.0/schemas/`.

So you can install your schema to `/opt/<yourapp>/share/glib-2.0/schemas`, then have your binary add `/opt/<yourapp>/share` to the XDG_DATA_DIR environment variable before you try to use GSettings.

This is what we do for Quickly apps being installed into `/opt/extra.ubuntu.com/<appname>/`

Comment: Works fine. The only issue is if a user opens `dconf-editor`, then he/she will see a set of keys with no associated schema. But that's OK, and is for investigation for now.